# How To trigger script on particular instance

Tags: unix

I have a main_script.sh which runs every day and scheduled in crontab.

in the main script i read data from config file

i Need to print based on below. for eg apple and mango should not run on sunday. Main_script will be keep running all days

apple - Monday to friday
mango - monday to saturday
orange - monday to sunday

```
test.config
apple
mango
orange

main_script.sh
for i in `cat test.config`
do 
if [ $i == 'apple' ]
then 
echo 'Apple'
..
..
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just grab the day of week using the `date` function and adjust your logic to check that as part of your conditions.

You can use a numeric date and three conditions:

```
dayofweek=$(date +%u)
if [ "$i" = "Apple" ] && [ "$dayofweek" -ge 1 ] && [ "$dayofweek" -le 5 ]
then echo "apple"
..
..
..
```

My original suggestion (this is just the outline... you would need to make the condition complete by checking all the relevant days)

```
dayofweek=$(date '+%A')
for i in `cat test.config`
do 
if [ "$i" = "apple" ] && [ [ "$dayofweek" = "Monday" ] || [ "$dayofweek" = "Tuesday" ] ... ]
then 
echo 'Apple'
..
..
..
```

Comment: Thanks.In this case i need to keep multiple conditions starting from monday-friday for apple and so on. The code will have too many conditions is there a alternative way

Comment: Either way it is only 3 conditions, but my original suggestion was not ideal. I've added a better solution (using a numeric value for the dayofweek so it can be checked with less-than/greater-than operators instead of string comparisons) and I've also clarified my original solution to show that it would be 3 conditions (although they would be long).